# Why are the Tkinter canvas lines jagged?

Tags: python, tkinter, antialiasing

The lines drawn on a `Tkinter.Canvas` are not smooth. How can they be made smooth?

Here's what I tried:

```
 from Tkinter import *
 root = Tk()
 cv = Canvas(root,bg = 'white')
 rt1 = cv.create_rectangle(10,10,110,110,width = 8,tags = ('r1','r2','r3'))

 def printRect(event):
     print 'rectangle'
 def printLine(event):
     print 'line'

 cv.tag_bind('r1','<Button-1>',printRect)
 cv.tag_bind('r1','<Button-3>',printLine)
 cv.create_line(10,20,200,200,width = 5,tags = 'r1')
 cv.pack()
 root.mainloop()
```

Here's what it looks like:

[image: tkinter output from sample code]

Answer (score 8):

`Tkinter` graphics are not anti-aliased which is why the diagonal line appears jagged. There may be a platform specific work-around like this one I found titled [Drawing Anti-Aliased Graphics Under Tkinter/Windows](https://web.archive.org/web/20200629063636id_/http://effbot.org/zone/tkinter-aggdraw.htm) to provide the functionality you desire.

Answer (score 1):

You might try to do some antialiasing of the poor, by drawing a clearer colored one pixel larger second line before (under) the first one.

Comment: found an example of applying this approach: https://github.com/vlachoudis/bCNC/issues/986

Comment: I see that they only add half a pixel (which means a quarter on each side. I wonder which one is best and why.

Answer (score 0):

1. draw an antialias image (using Image PIL ,numpy,opencv  etc)
2. show the image on the canvas.