# Drawing anti-aliased lines on Tkinter canvas in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

I am using Tkinter and Python 2.7.3 on windows 7 to develop my GUI. As a part my GUI I am drawing lines using `Canvas.create_line(x0,y0,x1,y0)` but my line is not smooth, it is coming like steps. How to get a smooth line?

Example Code:

```
from Tkinter import *
master = Tk()
w = Canvas(master, width=800, height=600)
w.pack()
w.create_line(100, 100, 400, 300, width=5)
mainloop()
```

Just like in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12436147/why-are-the-tkinter-canvas-lines-jagged) here i cannot use `aggdraw` as i am using 2.7 and also i used a lot of canvas config method.

How can i achieve this with out using `aggdraw`? And I've tried smooth option in `create_line` but no use.

Comment: Why does `aggdraw` not work? It should.

Comment: i tried it in python 2.6 it is working but it is not in my options..

Answer (score 0):

I really don't think you can get any more smoother than that. The `aggdraw` also won't do any better than that because the final *smoothness* depends on the pixel size (DPI) of the screen. Try looking at the line from a considerable distance, now increase the distance, see the increased *smoothness*?

Comment: my statement here is a comparitive statement. on the same screen one is giving good and another is not giving.. so looking from distance and/or increasing line length is not my option..