# How can I improve tkinter fonts (anaconda python 2.7)?

Tags: python, linux, tkinter, fonts

I am designing a GUI in tkinter and I see a difference in rendered fonts.
The fonts look pixelated on linux. On windows they are clear.

a)

[image]

b)

[image]

a) is linux and b) is Windows.

Is there a way to fix the pixelated fonts? I can fix things like settings by
using an image, but can we fix the fonts in a Text widget or listbox? I am using
subscripts for equations. Since there are a lot of equations, it is becoming
difficult to read (I can read it of course but not soothing to eyes).

Thanks

Comment: This might be related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12436147/why-are-the-tkinter-canvas-lines-jagged

Comment: @MatrixManAtYrService Thanks for the pointer. I was looking more for an option that can be used to control the behavior. Maybe Anti-aliasing = True or something.