# Creating rounded UI elements in tkinter without any images

Tags: tkinter

I've seen a lot of people suggesting to make use of images for this solutions but I'd rather not use images.

This is the UI I'm trying to replicate within tkinter
[enter main page UI description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qn8B9.png)

And I've managed to make some elements for it but they all contain square edges where as I want round edges.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/60558959/3885246

Comment: @IcyIcicle The button has extreme aliasing when its rendered.

Comment: Does this answer your issue from your comment? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12436147/why-are-the-tkinter-canvas-lines-jagged

Comment: @IcyIcicle Yeah thats better thanks, I'm still considering just outright using customtkinter instead but I feel like styling with custom tkinter is a lot more limited.